# Energy potential involvign pressure and viscoscity?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, computational-physics, simulation, differential-equations

Making a really long explanation short. I am looking for an energy density function for an incompressible isotropic fluid that involves both viscoscity and pressure.

The reason is, there is a way to take really large time steps when simulating something using MPM, but it only works if one has an energy density function.

For example, for a neo hookean constitutive model the energy density function can be found in equation 46 of the [MPM 2016 siggraph course](https://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Ecffjiang/research/mpmcourse/mpmcourse.pdf):

$$\Psi(F) = \frac{\mu}{2}\bigg(tr(F^TF - d)\bigg) - \mu \log(J) + \frac{\lambda}{2}\log^2(J)$$.

In the same notes a stress tensor is derived through the use of equations 48 and 38.

[In these notes](https://nialltl.neocities.org/articles/mpm_guide) the stress is computed as follows:

```
// end goal, constitutive equation for isotropic fluid: 
// stress = -pressure * I + viscosity * (velocity_gradient + velocity_gradient_transposed)

float2x2 stress = math.float2x2(
    -pressure, 0, 
    0, -pressure
);

// velocity gradient - MLS-MPM eq. 17, where derivative of quadratic polynomial is linear
float2x2 dudv = p.C;

// build strain from the velocity gradient
float2x2 strain = dudv;
strain[0][1] = strain[1][0] = trace(dudv);

float2x2 viscosity_term = dynamic_viscosity * strain;
stress += viscosity_term;
```

Which comes from the [wikipedia description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newtonian_fluid#Incompressible_isotropic_case) of the stress tensor for a newtonian fluid.

This is fine for the forward Euler step the author of the notes is using in his demos, but I need an energy density function. GIven that for the neo-hookean model there is an energy density function associated with the stress tensor, I was hoping someone could point me to an energy density function for a Newtonian Fluid.

Comment: This question seems to be more on physics than computational science. Things like that are discussed in the Physics group, e.g., https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/102136/strain-energy-density-in-index-notation

Comment: I also don't understand the premise. Solids move towards a position of minimum energy, but fluids don't -- they might minimize the *action*, but there is no energy because fluid flow is almost always dissipative.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth The premise comes from a computational need rather than any theory. It's because a paper published in 2015 allows for really large time steps in simulations but only if one has a formulation for an energy density model for the system being simulated.